# Advice on mapping with custom information

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, rospy, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I first started using ROS, I didn't implement it to it's fullest extent and ended up writing code that was already written for me (much better none the less) and now I would like some direction on what I should do so that I don't go down this path again.

I'm working on mapping and navigation and would like to expand the amount of information that is kept in the map message. My current understanding is that, using slam_mapping, a laser scan is converted to a map topic which gets published. This map topic contains MapMetaData and an OccupancyGrid which says what the chances of collision with the robot is in a given spot on the map.

I would like to add more information to the map, for example (not what I'm actually doing, but same deal) storing temperature data as I build the map. I want to use what's already given to me to the fullest and utilize it properly. What should I do?

Currently, this is my best idea:
Create my own topic type similar to that of the OccupancyGrid and instead of probability data, it will contain data about the temperature. If this is the way to go, how do I go about creating my own topic type?

All help greatly appreciated!

Blair

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40123/advice-on-mapping-with-custom-information/) by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You question is pretty open-ended. I doubt you will get many detailed answers.

Creating your own messages to provide additional information is indeed a reasonable solution to this general type of problem.

[This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages) explains how to create ROS messages of your own.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on 2012-08-01**:
Detailed answers are not what I'm looking for. I was looking for a "that seems reasonable" or "haha, why would you do that" or a "maybe you should think about..." So you answered my question well! Thanks for the advice!